# Team work - Helping the less talanted to take credit

Tags: human-resources

In the academic, government and corporate sectors, there are different definitions of team work. If we assume here that all members of a team are not equally senior, educated and experienced (or may be efficient) as is usually the case in many organizations; it is also indicative that some members may not be as efficient (may be talented) as we perceive them to be. It may also happen that one of the junior members of the team is more capable than the team leader.

If the team leader wishes to handle the team by

a). Asking the more capable and talented member to take responsibility for the less efficient member

b). Give all the credit to less efficient member if senior most official inquires in a meeting

does it actually help the team to grow? I found that (of course it may be due to cultural differences) if we force the less talented member to complete the task, it may lead to good practice of the individual but there are delays to counter with.

What if we sit alongside the member and take responsibility in completing the task? Is this way considered acceptable since I feel it addresses two aspects; first we create a sense of belonging for the less efficient member and second we also meet the scheduled date of completion.

@Lilienthal and @DJClayworth : I have modified the question.

@ Added after comments by @matt freake

So there are four people. A,B,C and D. A is the organization leader, B is team leader and C and D are members of the team. C is less efficient (or less productive). Now B requests D to take responsibility that was earlier given to C. D completes the task and helps C understand the details involved. B also appreciates both C & D that it was a joint effort. In the meeting with A, B informs the task was jointly completed by C & D and credits both of them. A knows that C could not have done the task; it was only D. But B maintains that it was both C & D; B also adds that ultimately the task is more important and that C is learning fast. A does not like B appreciating C; A tells B that C should have been forced to complete the task and D should not have been involved. A states that B is spoon-feeding C not allowing C to grow by its own.

Who is right? A since it wants C to grow on its own thereby "building" the team. B since it wants the team to "share and develop" and not allow C to think that "it is less efficient".

Comment: This sounds like a fascinating topic for an essay on an MBA course, but far too abstract for this site. In the workplace, you do what your superiors say (or find a different job).

Comment: This comes across as an actual situation cloaked as a rant about a philosophical definition.  We can't help you with philosophy (For philosophy questions see the room that's 3 doors down and on the right).  So what is the actual situation you have encountered?  And what is the concrete question about it.

Comment: Placing this question on hold for the reasons already given in other comments: you really need to specify what key workplace problem you're actually trying to solve. Neither philosophy nor semantics are really up our alley. :)

Comment: As soon as you use "less intelligent" in your definition it is unacceptable. To apply it you are going to have to label someone "less intelligent" and that will subjective, opionated, controversial and probably offensive. Destroy any writing with this definition in and hope nobody knows you wrote it.

Comment: If your manager forces you to do the work of others and forces you to give them all the credit for your work, you need to find a different team to work on (or you need to find new employer to work for). It's as simple as that. And yes, I would delete all references to the "less intelligent" comment. You may not be in the US, but in the US at least, this kind of comment could easily get you fired. You're not an expert on intelligence. And a less productive colleague doesn't mean that they're less intelligent.

Comment: @Suddhasattwa Ghosh . I think your improvements to the question are good but to get it reopened I think 1) describe the situation that actually happened (what the work was, how much you had to do, what the team leader said to the senior most official) and what the problem is and the goal you want to achieve (you want all the credit? you want credit for training the junior? you want to ensure your career is not hindered by this?)

Comment: I don't think anyone can tell you who is "right" (questions should be about concrete goals, not just if someone is right or it is acceptable). If A is in charge, they ultimately get to decide what happens. From your description I wouldn't want to work for A if they think someone should "forced to complete the task" and that one of their colleagues is "spoon-feeding"  them.

Comment: Please don't edit the question to change it completely.  It invalidates every answer and comment.  If you want to ask a different question please ask a new question.

Answer (score 3):

> So if I define team work as "A work ethic concept where all members do
> not have equal responsibilities but they work towards a common goal
> with the possibility of a specific member, either the senior most or
> one of the junior members, taking an added responsibility for another
> member if the latter is less intelligent and does not perform well but
> eventually shares the credit for the completed task." , would it be
> wrong?

Errr... No. How about just this:

A concept where all team members work towards a common goal. End.